# Datatrigger Not Firing Storyboard Or Not At All

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, datatrigger

I can not seem to get Data triggers to work no matter what I do. I'm trying to play a storyboard from the view model when a value changes yet nothing happens, no error, no cant find binding, just nothing... The code I'm currently attempting to get working is:

XAML:

```
<Page
 DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
 <Page.Resources>
   <DataTrigger x:Key="alertInDataTrigger" Binding="{Binding alert}" Value="1">
      <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource alertIn}" x:Name="alertIn_start"/>
      </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="alertIn_start" />
      </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
   </DataTrigger>

   <Storyboard x:Key="alertIn" Changed="visible" >
     <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="alert">
        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="729,2,2,658"/>
     </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
 <\Page.Resources>
```

C#:

```
public int alert
    {
        get { return this._alert; }
        set
        {
            if (this._alert != value)
            {
                int oldalert = this._alert;
                this._alert = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("alert");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can see the int alert properly changing to 1 and I know the pages bindings are working as all the other bindings on the page are properly showing their bindings yet I can not seem to get data triggers to work. I could use a little help on this stumper :/

Answer (score 0):

I see two things you are doing wrong. One is that triggers are should be added to the `Page.Triggers` not `Page.Resources`. The trigger will never fire if it is in the resources.

The other is `Storyboard.TargetName="alert"`. This should not be set to alert unless you have an element in the `Page` that is named alert. I believe that if you don't add `Story.TargetName` then it defaults to the current element which is the page. Otherwise, set the name of the element you want to animate its margin.